# How to share the data up from transcluded content angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a generic modal

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title [innerHTML]="data.title"></h1>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-content>
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<mat-dialog-actions>
 <button></button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

and i have the content for the modal

```
<modal>
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addNewPerson(person)">
    <mat-form-field>
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="firstName"
                       placeholder="First Name" matInput required>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</modal>
```

How can i send the data from this form in generic modal component? Thanks a lot

Sending data from child up to generic modal with @Output() doesn't work in this case. Also will be nice to see how to send data down in component from the generic modal, as we can do with @Input() in simple components hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom directive that grabs a reference to the `NgForm` directive

```
<form myFormDirective #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addNewPerson(person)">
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myFormDirective]',
})
export class MyFormDirective {
  constructor(form:NgForm, myService:MyService) {
    console.log(form.value);
    myService.theForm = form;
  }
}
```

then you can use a shared service to pass the `NgForm` reference along and on demand read the form value from [`theForm.value`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#value) or initiate some other actions.;

Comment: I would need to know where exactly the content is added. Modal content is usually added somewhere close to the body tag. I don't know the components he's using. But otherwise worth a try.

Comment: I don't understand from which event he wants to get data but i see `button` in his generic modal

Comment: I guess you'll come up with a stackblitz in ~2min and demonstrate how to do it correctly anyway :D

Comment: No, i don't have enough time:)

Comment: Glad to hear, so I have still a chance to earn some rep ;-). What are you working on?

Comment: @yurzui The data from form should be passed in generic modal, and when i'll click the save button from generic modal, then i should save the data from form component. Also when modal it's initialized i need to send some data from generic modal to form component. I hope that this explanation it's a bit clear

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i'll try your idea, hope to obtain some happiness after that :D